# How to remove double quotation marks and comma in the output when I input space for the first string (C++)

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a function to split the string and return it like a substring. The code is worked. I just meet a question: how to remove double quotation marks and comma in the output when I input space for the first string? Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;
vector<string> split(string targer, string delimiter);
int main()
{
   string s, delimiter;
   vector<string> tokens;
   cout << "Enter string to split:" << endl;
   getline (cin,s);
   cout << "Enter delimiter string:" << endl;
   getline (cin,delimiter);

   tokens = split(s, delimiter);
   cout << "The substrings are: ";
   for(int i = 0; i < tokens.size() - 1; i++)
  {
    if (tokens[i].length() != 0){
    cout << "\"" << tokens[i] << "\"" << "," << " ";
    }
  }
  if (tokens.size() != 0)
  {
    cout << "\"" << tokens[tokens.size() - 1] << "\"";
  }
  cout<<endl;
  return 0;
}
vector<string> split(string target, string delimiter){
stringstream ss(target);
string item;
vector<string> tokens;
while (getline(ss, item, delimiter.at(0))) {
    tokens.push_back(item);
 }
return tokens;
}
```

Comment: Please provide an example input and output to make the question clearer.

Comment: Can you give an example of an input with its expected output?

Comment: If my input is "[space], 1,2,", the expect output is "  "1","2" ", but my output is  " "", "1", "2" ".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is not "how to remove double quotation marks and comma in the output when I input space for the first string".

Your issue is correctly splitting the string, so that a quoted string that contains spaces gets correctly extracted as a single string.

The simple methods offered by the I/O library to parse input up until the next delimiting character is not sufficient in order to be able to handle splitting a string, in this manner, on its own. They don't know anything about quotes. You will have to do the job yourself:

1. Scan the input string one at a time, using the following logic.
2. If the current character is a delimiting character, continue to the next character.
3. If the current character is a quote, then continue to scan until the next quote character is seen, then extract everything between the quotes into a single word.
4. Otherwise, continue to scan until the next delimiting character is seen, and then extract everything until that point into a single word.

This is a basic high-level outline of a typical splitting algorithm. You will end up with individual extracted words, with quoted content as a single word. You can take this high-level overview, and rewrite it as a lower-level, more detailed algorithm, [then explain it to your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). After your rubber duck agrees that your detailed algorithm will work, you can then translate it directly into code.

Once you have implemented this correctly, you can refine this further to allow the quote characters themselves to be included in a quoted word. Typically that's done by using either two consecutive quotes, in a row, or a backslash "escape" character.